# C why booleans are one byte when they canreally be represented as one bit?

Tags: c, memory, boolean, ram

C why booleans are one bytes when they canreally be represented as one bit?
I am talking about stdbool.h.
Do the unecessary 7 bits of RAM go to waste?

Comment: Most CPU architectures do not let you allocate just 1 bit for a variable. And 1 byte does not have to be 8 bits

Comment: because in most case the cost of checking only 1 bit in memory is not worth saving 7 other bits, also how would the computer would use them ? that would require bit addressing. I other case CPU usually have flags that are represented by one bit, and you can have arrays of bool that are bitarray.

Comment: @Algo Byte is the minimal addressable unit.

Comment: @UnholySheep: “Allocation” is just humans deciding what memory will be used for. Computers have no say in that decision. Computer design affects whether bits are accessible individually, but they also effect whether bytes are accessible individually, and C can be implemented on processors which can only load and store words, not bytes. In fact, common processors do only load/store multiple bytes from/to memory; the accessibility of individual bytes is fabricated inside the processor. The accessibility of individual bits can be similarly fabricated with bitwise instructions.

Answer (score 7):

> why booleans are one bytes when they can really be represented as one bit?

Booleans are [*objects*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object). A bit is not an object in C because:

- It is not addressable via pointers. An object is [data storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model) of 1 or more bytes. A byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory.
- `sizeof` and `alignof` cannot be applied.

You still can represent your booleans with bits using bit-fields or toggling bits in an integer with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

How it is allocated is up to the compiler. A compiler may allocate a boolean as one bit if that makes sense for the CPU instruction set. Most CPUs cannot address bits, only bytes.

Still the compiler is free to cook up something like 1 byte containing space for up to 8 boolean allocations, if it wants. But in practice, that would probably be an optimization for space at the cost of execution speed.